# linking a subreport to a main report and have the data in the table match in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, subreport

I am trying to take a report that has employee pay data for a specific date range.  It works fine.  My problem is I need to take and put in YTD data of hours worked and total paid from the beginning of the year to the ending date parameter.  I created a subreport that gets me that data.  What I am having trouble with is getting the subreport to return the data, per employee, in line with the main data.  When I used Crystal Reports I could link the main table to the subreport without creating parameters.  Not sure if there is an equivalent or a work around.  Thanks in advance
Mike

Comment: How are you embedding the subreport in your main?

Comment: I have tried adding a column, inserting the subreport and linking the parameters.  I actually need to link the employee id but it isn't a parameter in either report as I want them all.

Comment: If the employee is not available then how are you displaying it on the report? You can bind a subreport's parameter to a field value from the main report.

Comment: I think you are going about this the wrong way. Post a sample of dummy data, then post what you are expecting as output making sure the numbers match your sample data so it's easier for people helping to understand. Do a mockup in Excel if you need and take a screen grab.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  The main report will get me all the employees paid in a date range.  The subreport should piggy back by giving the YTD number of hours and total pay from Jan 1 to the end date of the main report.  Since I can't get the YTD numbers on the main report  I have the main report that totals each employee's fields like 401K withheld, company matching, SSN, Address.  That subtotal is the data needed for the 401K company needing the data.  There are two fields that are in the subreport that I need.  It is the subtotal for YTD hours and YTD pay.  That report returns data perfect.

Comment: I don't see a method of uploading a spreadsheet example.  If you know of one please let me know.  Thanks!